# How to retrieve current color from a Cario Context in Vala?

Tags: cairo, vala

I need to retrieve the current color before applying a new color so that later on I can replace it back.

```
var old_color = ctx.something ()?
ctx.set_source_rgb (new_color.r, new_color.g, new_color.b);// Apply new color
// Do some drawing
ctx.set_source_rgb (old_color.r, old_color,g, old_color.b);// Restore old color 
// Do some more drawing
```

I cannot see anything closely related to something like get_source_rgb () in the valadoc manual.

Comment: I don't remember the Cairo API well enough to answer this with certainty, but can use `cairo.Context.push_group` / `cairo.Context.pop_group_to_source`?

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot see anything closely related to something like get_source_rgb () in the valadoc manual.

The function you are looking for is `get_source()`. `set_source_rgb()` is a shorthand for `cairo_set_source(cr, cairo_pattern_create_rgba(r, g, b, 0))`. That's why there is no `get_source_rgb`.

(This example uses the C syntax since I do not know how this is mapped to Vala; the API docs should be able to answer this question. Also, I am not entirely sure about the memory management in my example above, but that shouldn't be a concern for Vala)

If you really want to get the current source RGB color, you need something like (again C, sorry):

```c
double r, g, b, a;
// This assert fails if the pattern is not an RGBA pattern
assert(cairo_pattern_get_rgba(cairo_get_source(cr), &r, &g, &b, &a) == CAIRO_STATUS_SUCCESS);
```

Edit: Beware, the above is bad code. Never do something with side effects in `assert` since it would fail if `assert` is disabled. I'll keep the example like this for simplicity.

> so that later on I can replace it back.

So, what you are actually looking for is `cairo_save(cr)` and `cairo_restore(cr)`. Those are the C functions, so I guess you want `ctx.save()` and `ctx.restore()`.

What they do: All of the drawing state (except the current path) is saved. Restoring then undoes any changes that were done.

Comment: I'm trying to decipher this, but I'm having trouble. As a last resort I 'll try save and restore, but I'm not sure what the consequence of restoring the drawing state will be. As far as cairo_pattern_get_rgba, I cannot find this anywhere in the cairo.vapi file. All I can find is cairo_pattern_create_rgba which is a creation method. I think I'll need to play around with some c source first to get a better understanding.

Comment: I've confirmed that the above solution does work in c, but not in vala. I've raised an issue. https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vala/-/issues/1381

Comment: Well, save/restore has no consequences! If you just call save and then immediately restore, nothing happens. If you e.g. change the source color in between the two calls, then that will be reverted. Short version: Restore only undoes whatever you did yourself since the last save.